How to list ALL resources in an Azure Subscription
Can someone let me know how go about obtaining all the resources within an Azure Subscription. I tried the following:
az resource list

The above just spewed out a lot of JSON that didn't really make any sense.

Json is the default output format of Azure CLI. What exactly do you need to list? Just the resource names?

query in azure resource graph resource table is another way.

The JSON that it spewed out is a JSON Array that gives information about each resource in a JSON object such as location, resource group, tags, sku (if applicable), id, created and changed time and more. I think you might only want name and resource type in which case you can add query to that command like -
az resource list --query "[].{Name:name, Type:type}" --output table


The Azure CLI uses JSON as its default output format, but offers other formats, including (but not limited to):

table: ASCII table with keys as column headings
tsv: Tab-separated values, with no keys
yaml: YAML, a human-readable alternative to JSON

Use the --output (--out or -o) parameter to format CLI output.
Example
Get the names of the resources in a subscription:
az resource list –query "[].name" -o tsv --subscription NAME_OR_ID

Example output:
DemoVM010
demovm212
KBDemo001VM
KBDemo020


thanks for getting in touch. Can you give me an example of "[].name" please.

Also, are there any tools let allow you to map out the resources in a Subscription or resource group?

What do you mean by `example of "[].name"? I already provided an example output - names of the resources will be displayed in the console/output.

Rui, sorry I wasn't making sense. Thank you
